# How to pass multiple parameters (Objects) in IActionResult Asp.net WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
[HttpPost("addtocart")]
        public IActionResult AddToCart( Cart cart,
                                        Product product,
                                        ProductOption productOption
                                       )
        {
            _cartService.Add(cart);
            _productService.Add(product);
            _productOptionService.Add(productOption);

            return NoContent();
        }
```

Why I cannot use IActionResult with multiple parameters and how to solve this issue

Comment: Presumably with a containing object that holds all 3. Is this ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core? Please only tag the one you're using.

Comment: @Llama  Its a controller

Comment: Why does `AddToCart` seemingly serve to create a cart, product, and product option? I would expect a cart to exist, a product to exist, and for you to be adding an entry for that product in the cart, along with any chosen options.

Comment: It doesnt even work  It gives error as soon as I click on start..  It says you cannot use multiple parameters.

Comment: Create a class that contains three properties (Cart, Product, and ProductOption). Make the method accept that. I still think your method functionality is probably very wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to post all of those in 1 operation, you need to wrap them in some object.

```
public class Something
{
    public Cart Cart {get;set;}
    public Product Product {get;set;}
    public ProductOption ProductOption {get;set;}
}
```

and then take that in from the body of your request

```
[HttpPost("addtocart")]
public IActionResult AddToCart([FromBody] Something something)
{
    _cartService.Add(something.Cart);
    _productService.Add(something.Product);
    _productOptionService.Add(something.ProductOption);

    return NoContent();
}
```